# JSON schemas jest testing with oneOf

Tags: node.js, json, jestjs, schema, fastify

I have the following schema (required body must contain 'second' or 'third'):

```
const schema = {
  body: {
    oneOf: [
      { required: [
        'first',
        'second',
      ] }, { required: [
        'first',
        'third',
      ] },
    ],
    properties: {
      first: {
        type: 'string',
      },
      second: {
        type: 'string',
      },
      third: {
        type: 'string',
      },
    },
    type: 'object',
  }
};
```

Then schema testing is performed by Jest:

```
expect(schema.body.required).toEqual([
  'first',
  'second',
]);
```

Current test result is:

Expected: ["first", "second"]
Received: undefined

So it receives non of the required options. How to rewrite schema or/and test correctly?

PS: schema had only

```
required: [ 'first', 'second' ]
```

before (without oneOf), and test had passed

Comment: I suppose I just have to compare with { oneOf: ... } object...

Comment: please add you test code. The field `schema.body.required` does not exist in the `schema` object so it is correct.